# How can I show Location with using C# Microsoft Bot Builder Location

Tags: c#, botframework

I use below code:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Location;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LocationBotDemo.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MainDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedStart);
        }
        public async Task MessageReceivedStart(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;

            var apiKey = Keys.bingMapsKey;
            var prompt = "Where should I ship your order? Type or say an address.";
            var locationDialog = new LocationDialog(apiKey, message.ChannelId, prompt, LocationOptions.None, LocationRequiredFields.StreetAddress | LocationRequiredFields.PostalCode);
            context.Call(locationDialog, AfterLocationProvided);            
        }

        private async Task AfterLocationProvided(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var message = await result;
            // loop back to beginning
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedStart);
        }
    }
}
```

But

```
var locationDialog = new LocationDialog(apiKey, message.ChannelId, prompt, LocationOptions.None, LocationRequiredFields.StreetAddress | LocationRequiredFields.PostalCode);
```

Above line asking the user for the location, street and postal code. I dont want that. I want to show location without asking anything to user.

For example I want to show " The Mall, Westminster, London SW1A 2WH, UK " without asking anything to user. How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that with the Bot Framework. What you can do is use an API like the [Bing Maps API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx) and generate an image of a map with a pushpin on it, then send that image as a [file attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-media-attachments) or a [card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments) to the user. By the way, this is exact API that the LocationDialog you've mentioned in your question uses under the hood as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

> want to show location without asking anything to user

As far as I know, not all of the channels allow users to share their location, if the user’s message that sent from the specific channel do not contain location information in message entity, you will not be able to retrieve user’s location in your bot application via message entity.

As you did, if the channel currently does not support sharing their location, you can prompt user for location information in bot application. And we can use [Bing location control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) to collect and validate the user's desired location.

Besides, the following github issues discussed similar question: getting user location from specific channel, you can check the link to get details.

- [Bot c#: How can I get user location and time zone on the device from
  the bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2626)
- [How to get user's location details for BOT using Microsoft Teams](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2690)
- [[Telegram] Get user location](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1595)

Comment: I don't want to show user’s location. I want show specific location like " The Mall, Westminster, London SW1A 2WH, UK ".

Comment: `show specific location like " The Mall, Westminster, London SW1A 2WH, UK "` As I mentioned in my reply, if message entity does not contain location information, we need to prompt user for location information. If you want show the location on map, you can call some Maps API.